Contract Execution always fails while calling the flash loan with 1Inch API
I am getting the data from the 1inch api and I am using this contract for executing the flash loan. However, almost all the transactions are failed with the message, "Transaction Reverted Silently". Since some of the transactions actually went through, I am confused on how to actually debug what is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated,
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@balancer-labs/v2-interfaces/contracts/vault/IVault.sol";
import "@balancer-labs/v2-interfaces/contracts/vault/IFlashLoanRecipient.sol";

// import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract FlashLoanSwapper is IFlashLoanRecipient {
    IVault private constant vault =
        IVault(0xBA12222222228d8Ba445958a75a0704d566BF2C8);
    address public oneInchRouterAddress;
    event ErrorCaught(string indexed swapStep, string error);

    constructor(address _oneInchRouterAddress) {
        oneInchRouterAddress = _oneInchRouterAddress;
    }

    function initiateFlashLoan(
        address token,
        address tokenOut,
        uint256 amount,
        bytes memory swapData1,
        bytes memory swapData2
    ) external payable {
        IERC20[] memory tokens = new IERC20[](1);
        uint256[] memory amounts = new uint256[](1);
        tokens[0] = IERC20(token);
        amounts[0] = amount;

        // Pack swap data into userData
        bytes memory userData = abi.encode(swapData1, swapData2, tokenOut);

        vault.flashLoan(this, tokens, amounts, userData);
    }

    function receiveFlashLoan(
        IERC20[] memory tokens,
        uint256[] memory amounts,
        uint256[] memory feeAmounts,
        bytes memory userData
    ) external override {
        require(msg.sender == address(vault), "Caller is not the Vault");
        require(tokens.length == 1, "Should only handle one token");

        // Decode userData to get swap data
        (bytes memory swapData1, bytes memory swapData2, address tokenOut) = abi
            .decode(userData, (bytes, bytes, address));
        //
        // Perform the swaps
        executeSwap(swapData1, address(tokens[0]), "First Swap");
        executeSwap(swapData2, address(tokenOut), "Second Swap");
        

        // Repay the flash loan
        uint256 totalRepayment = amounts[0] + feeAmounts[0];
        require(
            tokens[0].transfer(address(vault), totalRepayment),
            "Failed to repay flash loan"
        );
    }

    function executeSwap(
        bytes memory swapData,
        address tokenIn,
        string memory swapStep
    ) internal {
        // Ensure the contract has enough allowance to give to 1inch
        if (tokenIn != address(0xEeeeeEeeeEeEeeEeEeEeeEEEeeeeEeeeeeeeEEeE)) {
            require(
                IERC20(tokenIn).approve(
                    oneInchRouterAddress,
                    type(uint256).max
                ),
                "Approval failed"
            );
        }
        (bool success, bytes memory returnData) = oneInchRouterAddress.call{
            value: msg.value
        }(swapData);
        if (!success) {
            string memory errorMessage = getRevertMsg(returnData);
            emit ErrorCaught(swapStep, errorMessage);
            revert(errorMessage);
        }
       
    }

    // Helper function to extract the revert message from a failed call
    function getRevertMsg(bytes memory returnData)
        private
        pure
        returns (string memory)
    {
        if (returnData.length < 68) return "Transaction reverted silently";
        assembly {
            returnData := add(returnData, 0x04)
        }
        return abi.decode(returnData, (string));
    }
}

